# Jenkins with mercurial: Set repository url as parameter

Tags: mercurial, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is it possible to use Jenkins with Mercurial in a way that a job will have the mercurial repository URL as a parameter?

This will allow us to use a single job that can clone and build different repositories. This build is for testing only. An official build and release will be from a constant repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Job Configuration page, check the 'This build is parameterized' option.

You should be able to define a named parameter for your repository and then reference that in the build configuration further down. In my set up, I do this to allow named branches in Mercurial to built.

You'll have to manually specify the parameter when you trigger the build.

Comment: Wow! it actually works :-) Is this a new feature that was added to the Jenkins Mercurial plugin? As long as it works... Thx!

Comment: I can't recall specifically, but you may have needed a plugin previously to do something similar.